# Should I store unique string into _id if the string too long in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, design-patterns, indexing

I am implementing a crawler to get data from Youtube and I need to store the id (ex: UCZ0zEZe8pWhmNpPdzwfxx4B) of each channel into my database (using MongoDB 4.0). I want to store these id given the following conditions:

1. The id field must be indexed
2. Not use too much memory for indexing
3. No need to hash the id into other shorter string (if possible)

Currently, I have 2 solutions:

- Solution 1: store channel_id and set the index like following

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("522bb79455449d881b004d27"),
   "channel_id": "UCZ0zEZe8pWhmNpPdzwfxx4B",
}
db.channels.createIndex({'channel_id':'hashed'})
```

- Solution 2: store channel_id into _id and using default index of _id

```
{
   "_id": "UCZ0zEZe8pWhmNpPdzwfxx4B",
}
```

The solution 1 satisfy condition (1), (2), (3) but field _id seems useless because channel_id will be used like primary_key for this collection

The solution 2 satisfy condition (1), (3) and need more memory for indexing

I think solution 1 is better in this case but is there any pros and cons?
What is the best practices to save the long unique string (with indexing) in MongoDB ?

Comment: Why do you feel Solution-2 needs more memory for indexing? It shoul still consume less memory than Solution-1 as there will be only one index for the collection.

Comment: @Jay, I created a temporary database and insert 1 million records, each record contains channel id with 24 characters. If I create hashed index ({'channel_id': 'hashed'}, the index size will be 37.8 Mb while the other index ({'channel_id': 1}) is around 68 Mb

Comment: What was the memory when you used '_id' field itself to store 'channel_id' value?

Comment: Another test with 2 million records and use '_id' field to store channel_id' value (Ex: { "_id" : "MaTJF7tm5zzYtL5SiJSCoQ==" }), the memory usages when I run stats: {"totalIndexSize" : 189001728,
 "indexSizes" : {
  "_id_" : 151191552,
  "_id_hashed" : 37810176
 }}

Comment: @Jay I sorry, the previous test has 2 million records, too.